# MapKit doesn't come with venue names?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, mkmapview, mapkit

This must be a super newbie question, but I'm just starting out with Mapkit and it seems that the venue names which I took for granted don't come with Mapkit right out of the box. The version I see only has street names and that's all. No "apple store", no "central park", nothing, but just boxes that resemble buildings. Here's what it looks like on my iPhone:

[image: fully zoomed mkmapview]

So my question is: Is there really no setting or anything that I can simply turn on to display some more venue information on top of those boxes, like how google maps does (or even Apple's own map app does!)

Comment: Do you have a screen hot of the same place at the same zoom with the venue names you say ate missing?

Comment: @craig if you mean the same place at the same zoom on my maps app, here's what it shows: http://i.imgur.com/ohJuoDo.png , you know, this is pretty common in maps, so i was surprised to find that I don't see *any* of these when I'm using MapKit, no matter which zoom level and no matter which location I'm looking at. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: The screen shot you have linked to is showing the map in 3D view. Are you asking how to have 3D maps in your app?

Comment: No, I am just talking about the venue names embedded in the map (Rayuela, Apizz Restaurant, Gentleman Farmer, etc.). Apple Maps app displays all these points inline, but my MapKit app doesn't include any, no matter how much I zoom or look around. I was curious if there is an option to turn this on, or if I need to look up a third party (or Apple's own) database in realtime and fill them in somehow.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of Apple Maps in non-3D mode showing those POIs (points of interest)? The extra screenshot you provided is running Apple Maps in 3D mode, which your app is not. So that could explain the difference. If Apple also shows those points in non-3D mode then you've got an actual problem to solve. But so far you are not comparing apples with apples, if you'll pardon the pun :-)

Answer (score 0):

There are limited place names on the map as you can see in this screenshot but not as many as in the Maps app.

[image]